# foreach loop does not display the correct results

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, methods

I am having issues with my nested foreach loop. I'm trying to populate data from by database to my list with information about car information (company, different car models). My issue has to do with my inner loop, and not being able to continue populating my list.

The results that I'm expecting is this:

```
"CompanyId": 1,
"CompanyName": "Toyota"
"ParentVehicleId": 2,
"ParentVehicleName": "Camry",
"ChildVehicleId": 4,
"ChildVehicleName":"Camry/Scepter"

"CompanyId": 1,
"CompanyName": "Toyota"
"ParentVehicleId": 4,
"ParentVehicleName": "Crown"
"ChildVehicleId": 0,
"ChildVehicleName":"N/A"

"CompanyId": 12,
"CompanyName": "Hyundai"
"ParentVehicleId": 13,
"ParentVehicleName": "Accent",
"ChildVehicleId": 0,
"ChildVehicleName":"N/A"

etc...
```

But what I'm actually getting is only these two:

```
"CompanyId": 1,
"CompanyName": "Toyota"
"ParentVehicleId": 2,
"ParentVehicleName": "Camry",
"ChildVehicleId": 3,
"ChildVehicleName":"Camry/Vista"

"CompanyId": 1,
"CompanyName": "Toyota"
"ParentVehicleId": 2,
"ParentVehicleName": "Camry",
"ChildVehicleId": 4,
"ChildVehicleName":"Camry/Scepter"
```

This is a snippet of my db table:

> Vehicle Table

```
|----------------------------------------------|
| VehicleId    |  ManufactId  | BrandName      |
|----------------------------------------------|
|  1           |    1         | Toyota         |
|----------------------------------------------|
|  2           |    1         | Camry          |
|----------------------------------------------|
|  3           |    2         | Camry/Vista    |
|----------------------------------------------|
|  4           |    2         | Camry/Scepter  |
|----------------------------------------------|
|  5           |    4         | Crown          |
|----------------------------------------------|
|  6           |    5         | Supra          |
|----------------------------------------------|
```

> C# code

```
 public List<VehicleListModel>> VehicleMethod()
        {

            List<VehicleListModel> vehicleList = new List<VehicleListModel>();

            foreach (var item in companyInfo)
            {
                var parentInfo = _context.VehicleTable.Where(y => item.VehicleId == y.ManufactId).ToList();
                foreach (var item2 in parentInfo)
                {
                    var childInfo = _context.VehicleTable.Where(y => item2.VehicleId == y.ManufactId).ToList();

                    foreach (var item3 in childInfo)
                    {
                    VehicleListModel vehList = new VehicleListModel();

                        //if ChildVehicleId does not exist, 0 & N/A are 
                        //returned
                        vehList.CompanyId = item.VehicleId;
                        vehList.CompanyName = item?.BrandName ?? "N/A";

                        vehicleList.Add(vehList);

                    }
                }
            }
            return vehicleList;
        }
```

Comment: Shouldn't `var companyInfo = _context.VehicleTable.Where(x => x.ManufactId == null).ToList();` be `var companyInfo = _context.VehicleTable.Where(x => x.ManufactId != null).ToList();`. I mean `==` should be `!=`.

Comment: @preciousbetine actually, if I were wanting to get the company names and I'd, I would need `==` instead of `!=`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is basically how your data is connected.

Let's take Toyota:

```
|----------------------------------------------|----------------|
| VehicleId    |  ManufactId  |    BrandId     | BrandName      |
|----------------------------------------------|----------------|
|  1           |    null      |      1         | Toyota         |
|----------------------------------------------|----------------|
|  2           |    1         |      1         | Camry          |
|----------------------------------------------|----------------|
|  3           |    2         |      1         | Camry/Vista    |
|----------------------------------------------|----------------|
|  4           |    2         |      1         | Camry/Scepter  |
```

As you can see, the model Camry is the relationship between the versions and the company.

When VehicleId is 2 (from Camry) you look for records where ManufactId is 2 (Vista and Scepter).

For Nissan instead:

```
|----------------------------------------------|----------------|
| VehicleId    |  ManufactId  |    BrandId     | BrandName      |
|----------------------------------------------|----------------|
|  9           |    null      |      9         | Nissan         |
|----------------------------------------------|----------------|
|  10          |    9         |      9         | Datsun         |
|----------------------------------------------|----------------|
|  11          |    9         |      9         | Datsun 13T     |
```

Datsun doesn't have childs (no record have ManufactId equal to 10). Update Datsun 13 T record to ManufactId 10 to see it.

The same goes for the rest.

Moreover, because you hydrate the objects of the list inside the innermost foreach loop (and you never reach that code) you don't even get the empty objects.

If the data is wrong and you can't do anything about it, one possible way to handle these cases is to generate objects with the available info:

```
....

List<VehicleListModel> vehicleList = new List<VehicleListModel>();

var companies = _context.Where(x => x.ManufactId == null).ToList();

foreach (var company in companies)
{
    var models = _context.Where(y => company.VehicleId == y.ManufactId).ToList();
    if (models.Any())
    {
        foreach (var model in models)
        {
            var versions = _context.Where(y => model.VehicleId == y.ManufactId).ToList();
            if (versions.Any())
            {
                foreach (var version in versions)
                {
                    VehicleListModel vehList = new VehicleListModel();

                    vehList.CompanyId = company.VehicleId;
                    vehList.CompanyName = company?.BrandName ?? "N/A";
                    vehList.ParentVehicleId = model?.VehicleId ?? 0;
                    vehList.ParentVehicleName = model?.BrandName ?? "N/A";
                    vehList.ChildVehicleId = version?.VehicleId ?? 0;
                    vehList.ChildVehicleName = version?.BrandName ?? "N/A";

                    vehicleList.Add(vehList);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                VehicleListModel vehList = new VehicleListModel();

                vehList.CompanyId = company.VehicleId;
                vehList.CompanyName = company.BrandName;
                vehList.ParentVehicleId = model.VehicleId;
                vehList.ParentVehicleName = model.BrandName;
                vehList.ChildVehicleId = 0;
                vehList.ChildVehicleName = "N/A";

                vehicleList.Add(vehList);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        VehicleListModel vehList = new VehicleListModel();

        vehList.CompanyId = company.VehicleId;
        vehList.CompanyName = company.BrandName;
        vehList.ParentVehicleId = 0;
        vehList.ParentVehicleName = "N/A";
        vehList.ChildVehicleId = 0;
        vehList.ChildVehicleName = "N/A";

        vehicleList.Add(vehList);
    }
}

....
```

Also, as @Yair suggested, you need to change Crown to ManufactId = 1

Comment: I see what you mean. There should be a way to populate the empty objects with 0 and N/A. What's the best approach?

Comment: Well, you could first check if childInfo has values before doing the foreach, using if(!childInfo.Any()). Inside that, you could populate the object with data you do have, and hardcode 0s or N/A in the remaining properties (the ones you'd get inside the next foreach),

Comment: thank you for your response. I tried what you suggested, but that's not giving me the required result. I'm not sure how to proceed

Comment: so I've attempted the suggested code, but it still gives me the same result as before. This => `!childInfo.Any()` isn't working. What other checks should I do?

Comment: this is the correct answer but your data is incorrect for the rows with VehicleId id 5 and 6 you need to put 1 in column ManufactId.

Comment: @herman demczuk I'm getting some where this time around. How would this look like with a nested foreach loop?

Comment: @herman demczuk. Seems like it's working. I'm just noticing duplication in my results. Should I break out of the loop once it satisfies my condition?

Comment: I tried the code I shared using your data set and it doesn't duplicate results. You can update your question  to help us understand your new scenario, as the original question was already answered.

Comment: How would an if/else look like if you were going to look for nulls for the parents? You were able to check for nulls in the child, but lets say nulls exist in both child and parents. How would the foreach loop along with the if/else look like?

Comment: @HernanDemczuk would it look something like this => 
`var models = _context.Where(y => company.VehicleId == .ManufactId).ToList();
if(models.Any()){
        foreach (var model in models)
        {}
//continue with the rest of the code
}`

Comment: Code updated. Be sure to have the relationships right in your data set

Comment: @HernanDemczuk Thank you Hernan. It worked on my end. I appreciate your effort and explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding the `vehList` instance in each iteration. Instead, you should move its initialization to the inner most loop, so a new instance is added to the list in each iteration:

```
        foreach (var item in companyInfo)
        {
            var parentInfo = _context.VehicleTable.Where(y => item.VehicleId == y.ManufactId).ToList();
            foreach (var item2 in parentInfo)
            {
                // This should be removed from the code:
                // VehicleListModel vehList = new VehicleListModel();

                var childInfo = _context.VehicleTable.Where(y => item2.VehicleId == y.ManufactId).ToList();

                foreach (var item3 in childInfo)
                {
                    // Instead, it's initialized here:
                    VehicleListModel vehList = new VehicleListModel();

                    //if ChildVehicleId does not exist, 0 & N/A are 
                    //returned
                    vehList.CompanyId = item.VehicleId;
                    vehList.CompanyName = item?.BrandName ?? "N/A";
                    vehList.ParentVehicleId = item2?.VehicleId ?? 0;
                    vehList.ParentVehicleName = item2?.BrandName ?? "N/A";
                    vehList.ChildVehicleId = item3?.VehicleId ?? 0;
                    vehList.ChildVehicleName = item3?.BrandName ?? "N/A";

                    vehicleList.Add(vehList);

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. However, That still didn't work for me even after I moved my code within the 3rd nested foreach loop